# Android LinearLayout center TextView among others

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout with three TextViews foo, bar and baz. foo should be on the left, bar centered and baz on the right. This is what I got so far:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="baz" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I have is that bar is only centered, when foo and baz have the same size. Furthermore, the text of baz may change during program execution, making bar jump around to maintain equal distance to foo and baz.

I would like bar to *always* be centered within the LinearLayout, no matter the (possibly changing) size of foo and baz. How can I archive this?

Comment: What's the use of two textviews with 0 height and weight?

Comment: They provide the spacing between the actual TextViews with content. Their weight is relevant here.

Comment: The equal spacing can be provided by using layout_weight with the 3 textviews instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for. It will keep the middle `TextView` in the middle of the layout regardless of what the values of the left and right `TextView`s are (notice I've changed the text lengths from your foo and baz values).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="asdfasdfasdf" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="dfdfdf" />
</LinearLayout>
```